# How to view and bind an array with swing builder

Tags: swing, groovy

Currently, this shows 2 variables on the screen. Whenever that variable changes, it is also shown on the GUI.

I would like to bind array indexes in a similar way. For example: x[1],
and whenever x[1] changes, so does the value shows on GUI

EDIT: array x doesn't update, I also don't want the whole array but each index on a new line.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable

@Bindable
class controller{
    boolean stop = false;
    String status = "RUNNING";
    String name = "";
    String[] x= new String[5];
}
def ctrl = new controller();
def UI = new SwingBuilder().edt {
    frame(title: 'Menu', size: [220, 150], locationRelativeTo: null, show: true, alwaysOnTop: true){
        gridLayout(cols:1, rows: 5)
        label(text: bind(source: ctrl, sourceProperty: 'status', converter: { v ->  v? "Status: $v": ''}))
            label(text: bind(source: ctrl, sourceProperty: 'name', converter: { v ->  v? "$v": ''}))
            label(text: bind(source: ctrl, sourceProperty: 'x', converter: { v ->  v? "$v": ''}))
  }
}
for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
    sleep(500);
    ctrl.name+= "Hi there ";    
    ctrl.x[i] = "T"+i;
}
ctrl.status = "DONE";
sleep(1000);
UI.dispose();
```

Comment: Do you have a small runnable example that shows what you mean?

Comment: I added the runnable code, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't observe changes on an array using `@Bindable` in this way. The AST transformation is a convenience for registering methods that rely on `PropertyChange` and `PropertyChangeListener`.

Changes made to `name` and `status` properties work because you're replacing their value, thus a `PropertyChangeEvent` is triggered for every change. However for the `x` property you're not changing the array reference, but the elements within the array.

You have two options to make this work:

1. either observe changes on the index itself (add an Integer property to the `controller` class).
2. use an `ObservableList` instead of an array.

Personally I prefer option #1. You will have to use a converter such as

```
label(text: bind(source: ctrl, sourceProperty: 'index', converter: { v ->  v != -1? ctrl.x[v]: ''}))
```

Notice the use of `-1` to check for a selected index as a value of `0` would make the previous check (`v?`) fail due to Groovy Truth.

The `controller` class can be updated as follows

```
@Bindable
class controller{
    boolean stop = false;
    String status = "RUNNING";
    String name = "";
    String[] x= new String[5];
    int index = -1;
}
```